# What is ratio of the length $x$ to $y$ in quadrilateral $ABCD$?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

Problem:

[image]

Here is what I've tried:

[image]

I drew symmetry of $BC$ and $AB$ along $AC$. Now $AE$ is angle bisector of $\angle DAC$. It seems it is enough to only consider $\triangle ACD$ and segments in it, but I still can't see a connection between orange segment and green segment.

Comment: Think at the law of sines.

Comment: @dxiv Thanks for the hint! It is clear now, after some simplifications we get $$2x\sin(130^{\circ})=\frac{\sin(100^{\circ})}{\sin(40^{\circ})}y=AC$$ and it gives $x=y$.

Comment: Glad it helped, that looks right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in comments, you already solved using law of sines. Here is a construction that shows $x = y$.

[image]

Extend $CB$ and drop a perp from $A$. Also drop a perp from $D$ to $AC$.

As $\angle ACE = 30^\circ, AE = AC/2$ and $\angle ABE = 50^\circ$. Also, as $\triangle ADC$ is isosceles triangle, $AH = CH = AC/2$.

That leads to $\triangle ABE \cong \triangle ADH$ (by A-S-A) and hence $x = y$.

Comment: Very simple and elegant answer! Thank you!

Comment: you are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Construct a circle that has centre $D$ and radius $DA$ as in the picture below and create a circumscribed angle $\angle APC$ on the large arc $AC$.

Then $\angle APC=50$. When observing the quadrilateral $ABCP$. You can easily say that it is cyclic which means points $A, B, C, P$ lies on the circumference of the same circle. This leads that points B and P are lying on the circumference of the circle that has radius $y$

Finally $BD=y$ as $\triangle ABD$ is equilateral $x=y$

[image]

@Math Lover's solution is more logical than mine.